# Our website not appearing when searching site name under Google News Tab

Tags: google-news

I would like to ask that we are facing a big problem on our site since September 25, 2018. Our website's articles were showing up in Google News Top Stories and then it starts disappearing in Google News search slowly from September 25, 2018. However, we were not alone, as there were so many another publisher who have faced this problem and a long discussion on this topic has already been done on Google News Search Forum.

Now its been over 5 months and the issue is still here. However, since last month our post started appearing again on Google search Under News section. The articles are also indexing fast but the search result didn't show our site when searching the site name. As you can see on the image above our website articles didn't appear when searching site name. Anyone, please tell me what could be causing this issue?

[image]

Comment: Why is this an issue?   News search is for searching for news articles.   It isn't designed to return the home page of a website for brand searches.

Answer (score 1):

Your brand's website is not at the top in normal searches of your brand, either. A brand's social media outranking a brand's own website often means that the website is very new and/or has very few backlinks and reputation.

I would recommend [working on your SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) to bring your site to the top of the SERPs for "techcarving" (preferably with [sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)), then your site may have enough reputation that Google will start showing it more prominently on the news tab too.

[image: techcarving serp]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would like to tell you that just after starting this website our started appearing Google's Top Stories and we know that appearing in Top stories always is not guaranteed. However, in the start, we just moved to the WordPress, installed simple plugins and started covering breaking news on our website and within two months Google started showing our post in Top Stories. Everything was going perfectly and then starting from September 25 our articles disappearing from Google News section, it still appearing you can see our recent post index there, but

Comment: We a second site approved in Google News and its appears perfectly on Under Google News tab. It's really simple when you search any website name you find that website in Google News tab on Google search if it is approved in Google News. if it is not approved in Google News then you won't find that website appearing Under Google News tab. Our website techcarving.com is also a verified Google News site. But its doesn't appear when we sear search its name under Google News tab.